# Bootstrap Tabs or Alternatives?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have tabs like bootstrap .nav-tabs but instead of an anchor tag it will change the content below it?

Im looking for something like this:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

But without the anchor tags but will just change the active tab and change the content below it.

If bootstrap is not the best option let me know

Comment: I didn't understand well your question. You want a dynamic tab change ? Bootstrap offers that, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs. Using their javascript lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use button instead of anchor. You will need to click something to change the menu. Bootstrap has nav-pills class also which work for menu. Else you can create div instead of anchor tag, and write jquery to hide or display content. For showing the active tab, you can remove .active class from all other divs, and add it to current one clicked.

Bootstrap for tabs is a very easy to follow option. Stick with it if there is no other specific project requirement. For learning purpose, you can also give zurb foundation a try. It is also very good framework.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--<link href="CSS/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="1">Menu 1</a>
    <div class="1">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="2">Menu 2</a>
    <div class="2">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="3">Menu 3</a>
        <div class="3">
            <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.2, .3')
            .hide();
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#1").click(function(){
            $(".2, .3").hide();
            $(".1").show();
        });
        $("#2").click(function(){
            $(".1, .3").hide();
            $(".2").show();
        });
        $("#3").click(function(){
            $(".2, .1").hide();
            $(".3").show();
        });
    });
```

Ended up using this code Thx @amit